# Open attachments in new tab issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-form, attachments

I am trying to open list item attachments in a new tab (when user clicks on an attachment in display form)

I am using this piece of jQuery/javascript in my custom display form to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("table#idAttachmentsTable a").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url=$(this).attr('href');
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
    });
```

Now when user clicks on the attachment, it opens in a new tab, but when you close that new tab and return to main tab, it still opens an attachment there (again).

What am I missing to stop it from doing this?

I've tried adding `return false;` at the end, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Which SharePoint Version & Browser are you using?

Comment: It's a Sharepoint Online environment, I need this to work on IE, Chrome and Firefox, it doesn't work on any of these at the moment :/ @Hardik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just resolved my issue.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659032/override-all-javascript-events-bound-to-an-element-with-a-single-new-event) question's answer and added

```
.attr('onclick', '')
```

This clears the `onclick` attribute in the html.

So my code now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("table#idAttachmentsTable a").attr('onclick', '').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url=$(this).attr('href');
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
    });
```

Comment: how would it be done for .PDF files / links only.??

Comment: Where did you put this piece of jQuery/javascript?

Comment: @A.Miller inside the DispForm.aspx file, using SharePoint Designer